# What is happening when one provides a pandas Series object as an index to another pandas Series object?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just getting started in `pandas` and found myself a bit stumped by the result of this code.

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5],['a','b','c','d','e'])

print (s[s > s.median()])
```

A `series` object, with data and indices greater than the median of s, is returned. How is a series object returned when it's supplied a series object as an index?  Why doesn't this return a type error?

another example, why does `s[s-2]` return a `series` with the last index moved to the top? I don't understand what is going on behind the scenes here. could someone help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

A `pandas.Series` has values and indices, in this case we have:

```
s.values #array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
s.index #Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='object')
```

You can access data directly by indices, e.g.;

```
s[1] #2
s[[3,4]]

#d    4
#e    5
```

You can also use "boolean indexing" which means you provide a list, or a pandas.Series, or a numpy.array, etc. with the same size of your Series and full of boolean values. E.g:

```
l = [True,True,False,False,True]
s[l]
#a    1
#b    2
#e    5
```

---

In your first case (`s[s > s.median()]`) you're using boolean indexing. Let's take a closer look

```
s.median() # is a number (3.0)
s > s.median() # is a Series of boolean values so we can use it for boolean indexing
#a    False
#b    False
#c    False
#d     True
#e     True

s[s > s.median()]
#d    4
#e    5
```

---

In your second case (`s[s-2]`) you are accessing data directly by index:

```
s-2 #is a Series
#a   -1
#b    0
#c    1
#d    2
#e    3

#we can use its values to access data
s[s-2]
#e    5
#a    1
#b    2
#c    3
#d    4
```